Is figure of speech scheme "X and Y, Y and X" historically safe to use?
I would like to vet a historical safety (meaning to make sure it was not invented or used by some villain in the past) of the following figure of speech scheme: "X and Y, Y and X". To give you a random example: "Honey and berries, berries and honey. This is what every respectable bear values the most, my friend!".
I doubt that I am an original inventor of this scheme and it definitely feels like I have heard it somewhere before. I just want to make sure it was not used by some Hitler of the world.
Does anyone know the historical origin of this scheme?

I'm assuming you're not simply talking about English, so I'd imagine that this sort of repetition for emphasis is as old as language so tracing the originator will be impossible. You might find the first recorded usage but that's unlikely to have much significance. As for the Hitler's of the world, I'm sure there's a villain, despot or tyrant who's used some form of this pattern at some point in their oratory.

This is exactly what I am afraid of, this scheme is too convenient for stating something evil like "Taxes and punishment, punishment and taxes, this is how you rule them all" type of thing. I am just wondering if there are famous historical examples that would make me want to steer clear of this figure of speech.

This figure is called "Antimetabole".

@carlosmartin The antimetabole changes the meaning of the phrase by reversing it, though.

Indeed, antimetabole reverses the meaning, while in case "X and Y, Y and X" the meaning does not change, it gets reinforced. So while it is close to antimetabole, it is not exactly it.
